# VSCodeでKotlinのDebug設定が出来ません

Tags: android, vscode, kotlin, debugging

#### 困っている事

VSCodeで、ktファイルのコンパイルと実行結果は表示できます。
しかし、VSCodeで、デバッグ(ステップイン等)が出来ません。
F5、F10、F11キーが、アクティブになりません。
ブレークポイントは入力できます。
F5→デバッガー窓に入力(FireFox等)が出来ません。デバッガー窓が消えます。
又、Web App(Chrome)を選択すると、settings.jsonで以下の内容が表示されます。

```js
{
    "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
    "json.schemas": [],
    "kotlin.languageServer.enabled": false,
    "kotlin.debugAdapter.enabled": false
}
```

#### 知りたい事

VSCodeでKotlinのデバッグ(ステップイン等でトレース)したいので、
settings.json、launch.json、tasks.json、extension.json等の
設定(具体的な書き込み必須コード)が知りたいです。
参考となるWebサイトが有れば、合わせて知りたいです。

目的は、スマホ単体で動作するAndroidアプリの開発のみです。
サーバー等での動作は、必要有りません。

#### PC環境

VSCodeに下記の拡張機能をインストール済です。

```
C:\Users\ユーザ名>code --list-extensions
firefox-devtools.vscode-firefox-debug
formulahendry.code-runner
fwcd.kotlin
mathiasfrohlich.Kotlin
mosapride.zenkaku
MS-CEINTL.vscode-language-pack-ja
oderwat.indent-rainbow
shardulm94.trailing-spaces
```

OS:Windows 8 64bit
VSCode
バージョン: 1.78.0 (user setup)
コミット: 252e5463d60e63238250799aef7375787f68b4ee
日付: 2023-05-03T20:09:00.748Z
Electron: 22.4.8
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 6.2.9200
Sandboxed: Yes

Comment: 拡張機能は入っているので、[実行]-[構成の追加]でKotlinが選べるはずです。とりあえず、launch.jsonを削除して上記のメニューを試してみるのはどうですか?